# Adding three new fields in MySQL database for newsletter

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, newsletter

I have basic knowledge around PHP and MySQL, but not enough knowledge to create a newsletter from scratch.

I found a newsletter tutorial on Git Hub which I liked and I would like to implement that newsletter in my website with some small changes.

I have added three extra fields in the HTML code (full name, phone number and URL)

I would like to add these three fields to the MySQL database when someone subscribes to the newsletter. Currently only signup id, email and sign up date is showing in the MySQL database.

If someone could help me with adding the three new fields in MySQL database, I would appreciate it. Been trying to make the newsletter work for some hours now without any luck.

**INDEX.HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
            <html>
                <head>
                    <meta charset="utf-8">
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                    <title>Ajax Newsletter Form</title>
                    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
                </head>
                <body>

                    <div id="newsletterform">
                        <div class="wrap">
                            <h3>Get Email Update</h3>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ullamcorper sapien luctus nisl laoreet, ac commodo tellus placerat. Etiam nec magna lacus. Curabitur quis felis vel nisl tincidunt hendrerit.</p>
                            <form action="send.php" method="post" id="newsletter" name="newsletter">
                                <input type="text" name="full-name" id="full-name" value="" placeholder="Full Name" />
                                <input type="email" name="signup-email" id="signup-email" value="" placeholder="E-mail Address" />
                                <input type="number" name="phone-number" id="phone-number" value="" placeholder="Phone Number" />
                                <input type="url" name="website-url" id="website-url" value="" placeholder="Website URL" />
                                <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="signup-button" id="signup-button">
                                <span class="arrow"></span>
                            </form>
                            <div id="response"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="assets/js/lib.js"></script>
                </body>
            </html>
```

**SEND.PHP**

```
<?php
require 'inc/Database.class.php';
require 'inc/Newsletter.class.php';

if (!empty($_POST)) {
  $text = $_POST['full-name'];
  $email = $_POST['signup-email'];
  $number = $_POST['phone-number'];

  Newsletter::register($email, $text, $number);
}
```

**CREATE_TABLE.SQL**

```
 CREATE TABLE `signups` (
   `signups_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `signup_email_address` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
   `signup_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`signups_id`)
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**DATABASE.CLASS.PHP**

```
<?php
class Database
{
private static $dbName = 'test_db';
private static $dbHost = 'localhost';
private static $dbUsername = 'test_admin';
private static $dbUserPassword = 'test123';

private static $cont = null;

public function __construct() {
    die('Init function is not allowed');
}

public static function connect() {
    if (null === self::$cont) {
        try {
            self::$cont =  new PDO('mysql:host='.self::$dbHost.'; dbname='.self::$dbName, self::$dbUsername, self::$dbUserPassword);
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    return self::$cont;
}

public static function disconnect() {
    self::$cont = null;
}
```

}

**NEWSLETTER.CLASS.PHP**

```
<?php
class Newsletter
{
private static $email;
private static $datetime = null;

private static $valid = true;

public function __construct() {
    die('Init function is not allowed');
}

public static function register($email) {
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        self::$email    = $_POST['signup-email'];
        self::$datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        if (empty(self::$email)) {
            $status  = "error";
            $message = "The email address field must not be blank";
            self::$valid = false;
        } else if (!filter_var(self::$email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $status  = "error";
            $message = "You must fill the field with a valid email address";
            self::$valid = false;
        }

        if (self::$valid) {
            $pdo = Database::connect();
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $existingSignup = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM signups WHERE signup_email_address='$email'");
            $existingSignup->execute();
            $data_exists = ($existingSignup->fetchColumn() > 0) ? true : false;

            if (!$data_exists) {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO signups (signup_email_address, signup_date) VALUES (:email, :datetime)";
                $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);

                $q->execute(
                    array(':email' => self::$email, ':datetime' => self::$datetime));

                if ($q) {
                    $status  = "success";
                    $message = "You have been successfully subscribed";
                } else {
                    $status  = "error";
                    $message = "An error occurred, please try again";
                }
            } else {
                $status  = "error";
                $message = "This email is already subscribed";
            }
        }

        $data = array(
            'status'  => $status,
            'message' => $message
        );

        echo json_encode($data);

        Database::disconnect();
    }
}
}
```

**LIB.JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#newsletter').submit(function () {
    var $this     = $(this),
        $response = $('#response'),
        $mail     = $('#signup-email'),
        testmail  = /^[^0-9][A-z0-9._%+-]+([.][A-z0-9_]+)*[@][A-z0-9_]+([.][A-z0-9_]+)*[.][A-z]{2,4}$/,
        hasError  = false;

    $response.find('p').remove();

    if (!testmail.test($mail.val())) {
        $response.html('<p class="error">Please enter a valid email</p>');
        hasError = true;
    }

    if (hasError === false) {

        $response.find('p').remove();
        $response.addClass('loading');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            url: $this.attr('action'),
            data: $this.serialize()
        }).done(function (data) {
            $response.removeClass('loading');
            $response.html('<p>'+data.message+'</p>');
        }).fail(function() {
            $response.removeClass('loading');
            $response.html('<p>An error occurred, please try again</p>');
        })
    }


    return false;
});
});
```

Comment: What is the problem you are actually facing ?

Comment: The code works fine, but I need to add three new fields as mentioned in the .php and .sql files i believe, but i am not sure which code I need to add so that the new fields are available in the MySQL Database when someone subscribes

Comment: Yeah, it's unclear what exactly you're having trouble with, and what you've tried already.

Comment: The code works fine without the three new fields i have added in the HTML, but i believe i also need to add some code in .PHP and .SQL  files so that the new fields can be saved in the database.

The problem is, i am not sure what code i need to add for the new fields in .PHP and .SQL. I hope this is enough info to make you understand what i am having trouble with

Comment: So you made your additions to `INDEX.HTML`. Now you need to make similar additions to `SEND.PHP`, `CREATE_TABLE.SQL`, `NEWSLETTER.CLASS.PHP`, and `LIB.JS` (`LIB.JS` only if you was js validation on the added inputs)

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems here :

SEND.PHP (missing url parameter)

```
<?php
require 'inc/Database.class.php';
require 'inc/Newsletter.class.php';

if (!empty($_POST)) {
  $name= $_POST['full-name'];
  $email = $_POST['signup-email'];
  $phone = $_POST['phone-number'];
  $url = $_POST['website-url'];

  Newsletter::register($email, $name, $phone, $url);
}
```

NEWSLETTER.CLASS.PHP (add your parameters in the register method and USE THEM)

```
public static function register($p_email, $p_name, $p_phone, $p_url) {
       self::$email    = $p_email;
       self::$datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
       self::$name     = $p_name;
       self::$phone   = $p_phone;
       self::$url      = $p_url;
```

CREATE_TABLE.SQL add these columns

```
 CREATE TABLE `signups` (
   `signups_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `signup_email_address` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
   `signup_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
   `signup_url` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
   `signup_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
   `signup_phone` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`signups_id`)
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

then add them into your sql insert :

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO signups (signup_email_address, signup_date, signup_url, signup_name, signup_phone) VALUES (:email, :datetime, :url, :name, :phone)";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(
                    array(':email' => self::$email, ':datetime' => self::$datetime), ':url' => self::$url, ':name' => self::$name, ':phone' => self::$phone);
```

Comment: I can't get it to work properly, i have added the new code and added new columns for mysql, i think the problem is the NEWSLETTER.CLASS.PHP

Everything works fine, except when i change the NEWSLETTER.CLASS.PHP then it doesn't work.

Maybe i am missing out on something.

Comment: I saw a variable mistake in my post sorry... in the '$number' should be '$phone' everywhere... I edited my answer

Comment: If it still doesn't work, try to add some var_dumps before the last part (the '$sql = "INSERT..."') to see the content of 'self::$email', datetime, phone etc... (and check if the program doesn't crash before that)

Answer (score 0):

Its simple. first your Create_table query will be like this

```
CREATE TABLE `signups` (
```

`signups_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `signup_email_address` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
   `signup_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    full_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    phone_number integer(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`signups_id`)
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

In 2nd step, check for whether the phone number, signup email and full name must not be null.

```
        self::$full_name= $_POST['full-name'];
        self::$PhoneNo= $_POST['phone-no'];
```

in 3rd step , make these changes in your insert query

> $sql = "INSERT INTO signups (signup_email_address, signup_date,full_name,phone_number) VALUES (:email, :datetime, :full_name, :phoneNo)";

Hope you got the idea

Answer (score -1):

In SEND.php you are sending three params but not receiving there in NEWSLETTER.CLASS.PHP

```
Newsletter::register($email, $text, $number); SEND.php

public static function register($email) { // NEWSLETTER.CLASS.PHP
```

Change it to,

```
public static function register($email, $text, $number) { // NEWSLETTER.CLASS.PHP
```

and then you need to optimize your query,

```
if (!$data_exists) {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO signups (signup_email_address, signup_date, db_field_name, db_field_email,db_field_number) VALUES (:email, :datetime, :any_variable_for_name, :any_variable_for_email, :any_variable_for_number)";
            $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);

            $q->execute(
                array(':email' => self::$email, ':datetime' => self::$datetime, ':any_variable_for_name' => $name, ':any_variable_for_email' => $email, ':any_variable_for_number' => $number));

            if ($q) {
                $status  = "success";
                $message = "You have been successfully subscribed";
            } else {
                $status  = "error";
                $message = "An error occurred, please try again";
            }
        } else {
            $status  = "error";
            $message = "This email is already subscribed";
        }
```

This may help you a little.